# OpenApi 3.0 string array inside body

Tags: openapi

In OpenApi 3.0 how do I pass string array inside requestBody?

I'm able to pass it as member of class, but since it is class with one field only, I'm looking for simpler solution.
When using:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    '*/*':
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
  required: true
```

I get error 415.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using application/json content does the trick. Although string array is not a typical json, it is treated as one.